# Can't install python-docx using pip

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, python-docx

I am very new to python and programming in generall. I am following a tutorial and tried to install python-docx using pip in the cmd, but it doesn't work.
Those are the errors i see:

```
DEPRECATION: lxml is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

and

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Can somebody help me with that problems in a way that even a newcomer like me understands it ?

I tried it with >pip install python-docx and >pip install python-docx==0.8.11 in the cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It worked after installing a manual build windows x64 wheel for python 3.11. See [github_lxml/lxml#356](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/356#issuecomment-1324905890)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error. Check if you have
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater. You can download it here. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
That has solved the problem for me

Comment: Sadly it didn't help me. I have still the following Error messages:
` DEPRECATION: lxml is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error `